# How to ignore dependencies for .NET Core during NuGet packaging?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I have my own NuGet packages located on a disk (local Nuget). I'm trying to not add the same DLL multiple times and get in a scenario like the image attached

I have tried the following code during packing but doesn't work

```
dotnet pack PathtoSolution\SystemCore.Services.Data --no-dependencies --output "G:\NuGetPackages"
```

However, during restoration to another project, the dependency comes back.

[image]

Is there a way to not include dependencies during the packing process or is ignoring at installation time my only option?

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your PackageReference `PrivateAssets="all"` - however this has some undesirable effects as well as you won't be able to access the types defined in those assemblies outside of your nuget package. If that's ok with you, it would work.

Comment: That can be a desirable effect if you don't want to expose the fact that you're using those dependencies, which would effectively make them part of your own public API.